# How to get Distinct Values from List(Of T) using Linq

Tags: vb.net, linq, list, distinct

I have a List(Of Hardware) - the List is called `HWModels`

Class Hardware has the following Properties:

- ModelName
- Status
- CPUStatus
- MemoryStatus
- DiskStatus

The List is populated by reading a CSV file, once it's populated, I want to return the distinct records based on the ModelName

I've attempted by doing it as follows:

```
(From a In HWModels Select a.ModelName).Distinct
```

But this isn't right because I end up with a list of only the ModelName's and nothing else.

How do I get the Distinct function to return all of the other class members within the list?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

LINQ to Objects doesn't provide anything to do "distinct by a projection" neatly. You could group by the name and then take the first element in each group, but that's pretty ugly.

My [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ) provides a [`DistinctBy`](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) method though - in C# you'd use:

```
var distinct = HWModels.DistinctBy(x => x.ModelName).ToList();
```

Presumably the VB would be something like

```
Dim distinct = HWModels.DistinctBy(Function(x) x.ModelName).ToList
```

Apologies for any syntax errors though :(

Comment: MoreLINQ library Google Code link is dead

Answer (score 18):

This will group your objects by the preferred property and then will select the first of each one, removing duplicates.

```
 Dim newlist = HWModels.GroupBy(Function(x) x.ModelName).Select(Function(x) x.First).ToList
```

Comment: this is an easy way to do what i needed, thanks Panteli