# Saving a list of words in visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

How do I create a program that identifies the individual words in a sentence and store them in a list? I want to then get the program to create a list of positions for words in that list save these lists as a single file.

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim WordNumber As Integer = 0
    Dim StartofWord As Integer = 1
    Dim Text As String = ""
    Dim L As Integer = 0
    Dim Word As String

    Console.WriteLine("Enter your sentence ")
    Dim LotsofText As String = UCase(Console.ReadLine)

    Console.WriteLine("Enter your word")
    Word = UCase(Console.ReadLine())


    If Mid(LotsofText, Len(LotsofText) - 1, 1) <> " " Then LotsofText = LotsofText + " "


    For L = 1 To LotsofText.Length
        If (Mid(LotsofText, L, 1)) = " " Then
            WordNumber = WordNumber + 1
            Text = (Mid(LotsofText, StartofWord, L - StartofWord))
            'Console.WriteLine(Text)
            StartofWord = L + 1

            If Text = Word Then
                Console.WriteLine(WordNumber)

            End If


        End If

    Next


    If Not Text = Word Then
        Console.WriteLine("Error word not found")

    End If


    Console.Write("Press Enter to Exit")
    Console.ReadLine()


End Sub
```

End Module

Comment: Think you might be looking for Linq. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645326/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-listof-t-using-linq

Comment: What defines a "Word" in your context? If it's just that it's separated by spaces, you can use `String.Split` to get an array of Words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Split` your sentence by blank `" "` , loop over all words and add the position to a list if the current word matches your search word.

```
Dim Sentence = "Hello from the other side and hello from hell"
Dim SearchWord = "Hello"

If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Sentence) Then
    SearchWord = SearchWord.Trim
    Sentence = Sentence.Trim
    Dim words = Sentence.Split(" ")
    If Not words.Contains(SearchWord) Then Return

    Dim searchWordPositions = New List(Of Integer)
    For i = 0 To words.Length - 1
        If words(i).Equals(SearchWord, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) Then
            searchWordPositions.Add(i)
        End If
    Next
    Console.WriteLine(String.Concat("Found '", SearchWord, "' at Positions: ", String.Join(", ", searchWordPositions)))
End If

'Output:
Found 'Hello' at Positions: 0, 6
```

Instead of `Console.WriteLine` write it to a file.